# MindManager will not display Excel range

Tags: excel, mind-manager

I'm trying to display a range from an Excel file in Mindjet Mindmanager using the menu option `Advanced > Excel Range`:

[image]

The selection itself seems to run smoothly:

[image]

But the corresponding range in the mindmap is empty:

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is an ancient topic, but here's my solution: Simply SAVE the excel-file after doing those steps. For me the data suddenly appears.